# SSRS range bar chart, different color when no data

Tags: reporting-services, charts, colors, sql-server-2008-r2, timeline

I am looking to change the color in the "gaps" in the range chart that I have built.

Essentially I am trying to build a visualization for the staff to see the availability on bays. The red markings mean the bay is booked, I wanted green then to be in between the red to highlight free bays.

Occupied bays:

[image: Occupied Bays]

I suspect I need to go back to my dataset and add in some date tables to show "null data" to allow a "switch" to work, but I thought someone might know if I could change this without going this way.

An example of the dataset would be:

[image: Data Set Example]

## Following up

here is a screen shot of my output, i added data labels to see if i was going wrong...HOWEVER I also added shadows to my data and my data is actually still there, just hiding behing my secondary bars......

[image: follow up data]

you are right about my data set, i had to add a series grouping to get my appointments all to appear other wise i was just getting the first appointments on the row only to appear....

[image]

## Following up 2

A further follow up, I have followed @iamdave 's excellent RangeChart.RDL

I have applied my dataset to it but I am now getting the following output, I know I am probably missing something simple, my gut is telling me the cust_id are seperating all the appointments on to seperate lines yet I have both the primary and secondary axis set to "DrawSideBySide = False"

Here is my set up..
[image: New Set Up]

here is my latest output, if I could just group all the rows/bars/lines down to the 6 bays it would be great.

[image]

Comment: Might not work for you, but how about a background fill of green?

Comment: Hi @WEI_DBA cheers for the suggestion, its a bit of a clunky approach to solving it but does look like its the only option available.

Comment: The only other way is to have a table with appointment times throughout the week (like a date table) and `LEFT JOIN` on that table and then fill those gaps with the green bar.

Comment: @WEI_DBA  That is not true.  SSRS is a very flexible visualisation tool, you just need to know where to look, as you can see from my answer below.

Comment: @iamdave, I stand corrected... and learned something! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by adding in another data series based on your original dataset, that will require significantly less processing than filling in all your empty periods as suggested by `WEI_DBA`.

1. In your dataset, add a new column that returns `dense_rank() over (order by BAY) as BayID` (`order by` should be your desired axis label).

   1. This may be best done as a wrapping `select` statement to preserve the rest of the query logic as is.
2. In your Range Chart, add in another `Values` item, with the same `Category Field` as your current one.
3. Set the `Top Value` to `1` and your `Bottom Value` to `0`.

   1. You could also set this to the `min` and `max` time of your dataset or the start and end period of your report to only cover the period the Bay was available.
4. Set it to display on the `Secondary Axis` for both `Vertical` and `Horizontal` axes.
5. Also select the `Do not show this series in a legend` option.
6. Set up the Secondary Vertical Axis in exactly the same way as your Primary Vertical axis.
7. Set the Secondary Horizontal Axis `Minimum` and `Maximum` to the same values as your `Bottom` and `Top` above.
8. Hide both the Secondary Axes.
9. Select the new `Values` item and in the `Properties` window, expand the `CustomAttributes` section and change `DrawSideBySide` to `False`.
10. If necessary, adjust the order of the `Values` items in your `Chart Data` window to make sure the new Range Bar displays underneath your actual data.
11. Select the original `Values` item and in the properties sidebar navigate to `Data > DataPoint`:

    1. Change `AxisLabel` to `=Fields!BAY.Value` (Your axis label).
    2. Change `Values > X` to `=Fields!BayID.Value` (Value from point 1.).

You should now have a range chart that that displays your data on top of a solid bar, that you can set to any colour you require:

[image]

Comment: Hi @iamdave, I have applied the method you have suggested but I am having a slightly unusual outcome. Only one or two of the red data points are appearing "over" the green "secondary" bar. I have gone over the steps multiple times just incase I have missed something as this is exactly what i am looking for. Thanks a million for the help thus far. If there is anything you need to know just let me know.

Comment: @unreal_event_horizon  Could you add a screenshot of your chart in Design View with the `Chart Data` pop up showing to your answer?  As the range bar for a series is treated as one object, it should either be entirely above or entirely below any other range bars in the chart.  This would suggest you have additional series or categories that need to be taken into account, or that either you have followed my steps incorrectly or I have documented them wrong

Comment: @unreal_event_horizon  If it helps, you can download the RDL file for this chart from [this WeTransfer link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/46831efdf1e6e9a44b12c1e8cd1bdf8220190311090529/59f842) (which will expire in 7 days)

Comment: thank you for the .rdl. Fantastic file, I brought it into my 2017 enviornment to see exactly what was done. However still hitting an issue as identifed in my edit (current resource issues means we are stuck on 2008 for the forseeable). Again thanks for the support.

Comment: @unreal_event_horizon  Ah I see what the issue is here.  You need to add in a continuous `BayID` value in the same order as you want them displayed on the chart.  I have added in some detail above and also uploaded [another WeTransfer share](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d008a8e6eda8688b0392c6df32daa13720190311151902/09a512).

Comment: perfect! i applied your updated sql change and axis data changes to what you already supplied and its now working flawlessly. I apparently dont have enough reputation to upvote your answer but I do really appreciate your help. I'll mark it as answered, will I edit my initial question post in anyway to help any newcomers?

Comment: @unreal_event_horizon  That's no problem :)  As you have marked this as the answer there is not need to add further detail to your question.  Between your situation and the solution in my answer others with the same problem should be able to find their way.

Comment: apologies for a follow up query. If I only want to display the open hours for each day when selecting more than one day, what would you advise? I. E. Only show between 7 and 6pm for each day so no green appears across midnight into the next day.

Comment: Without testing it I would imagine you would need to have a range for each day on your secondary axis, making sure both axes are set up to have the same min and max values.  This will require more complex processing however, as you will need to add in the additional data to your dataset.