# SQL SSRS Timeline Remove certain hours

Tags: datetime, charts, ssrs-2008

This may have been asked but I have looked and trawled the web but I may be searching incorrectly.

How do I get my x axis to only display hours I want, for example, I dont want any hours from 16 - 23 to appear or 0 to 6 to appear so that my Chart I am building only displays data concurrently rather than a "flat line" or null data for "out of hours" areas.

There is probably a straight forward piece of code for this but I am struggling.

On my X-axis "Scalar" doesnt appear so thats just a heads up.

If there is more information required please ask.

Follow Up Update:
SO i have worked on my report to do the following:

- when i select a date range of 1 day, i have set the start time to 7am and end time to 18:00 using dateadd("h",7,paramterstart.value) and similar to my end value.
- when i select the date range the report shows 1 day and the time line breaks down to to every half hour between 7 and 18.

Now when i select a date range longer that 1 day, i have the interval set to change to 1 and and interval type set as day. What Is happening is times outside of 18 to midnight to 7am are appearing.

Essentially its an availability viewer, but its oonly open certain hours.

My orginal question to build this was here, should I repost on that for further help?
[SSRS range bar chart, different color when no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55063682/ssrs-range-bar-chart-different-color-when-no-data)
[image: bay occupancy]

Comment: Can't you do a simple IIF?  `=IIF(Fields!hours.Value < 7 OR Fields!hours.Value > 15,...`

Comment: Hi @Steve-o169, apologies, would I put this IIF statement in my range on my x-axis,? Do I use "nothing" or null in the true element of the statement?